# How to have more than one expression in Google Analytics API DimensionFilter?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

This is my working code:

```
  request = {
      'startDate': flags.start_date,
      'endDate': flags.end_date,
      'dimensions': ['query','country','date'],
      'dimensionFilterGroups': [{
          'filters': [{
              'dimension': 'country',
              'expression': ['usa'] <--------------------- trying to add more country here
          }]
      }],
      'rowLimit': 5000
  }
  response = execute_request(service, flags.property_uri, request)
```

When i want to include more countries in my country dimension filter however, it doesnt work.

For example: 
I tried `'expression': ['usa','gbr']`

And i still only got `'usa'` results.

Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: is this google search console API request? I do not see this as Google Analytics API request

Comment: number of rows in response > 5000?

Answer (score 0):

That's because it only uses the first value in the list:

> …
>
> `expressions[]`: Strings or regular expression to match against. Only the first value of the list is used for comparison unless the operator is IN_LIST. If IN_LIST operator, then the entire list is used to filter the dimensions as explained in the description of the IN_LIST operator.
>
> …

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#dimensionfilter

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30908598)